# Angularjs : Loop all isolated scope Directive Templates, on click of one

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have html:

```
<div ng-repeat="mydata in data" class="ng-scope ng-binding">

   <p class="ng-binding">{{mydata.postdata}}</p> 
   <div my-rating rating-value="rating" data-cat="post" data-id="mydata.id" ></div>

   <div ng-repeat="childData in mydata.personRelatedData">
          {{childData.personName}}  
          <div my-rating rating-value="rating" data-cat="person" data-id="childData .id" >
   </div>
</div>
```

I have a Directive :

```
myDirectives.directive('myRating', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div><ul>' +
      '<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber)" ng-click="toggle($index)" id=$index>' +
      '<div ng-switch="switchPoint<$index">'+
      '<div ng-switch-when=true><img ng-src="img/{{Unrated}}"></div>'+
      '<div ng-switch-when=false><img ng-src="img/{{Rated}}"></div>'+
      ' </div>' +
      '</li></ul></div>',

    scope: {
      ratingValue: '=',         
        dataCat: '=',  
        dataId: '=',  
      readonly: '@',
      onRatingSelected: '&'     
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {       

      scope.toggle= function(val) {
        scope.ratingValue = val + 1;          
        scope.onRatingSelected({rating: null});
        scope.switchPoint = val;                    
      } 
    }      
}
```

Currently i have implemented that on page load, the rating from the db comes, and while rendering the template, if rating for that ID exists, then it is rated on the isolated rating template too.

Now what I want is that on click of a rating, the execution should rate that ID celebrity, but also loop the other isolated templates, to see if ratings for that ID exist.. and if so, we can update their rating too.

How can I loop the other isolated templates on click of one?

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the rating value in the scope of the directive, store the rating in a location that is accessible to all of the items.

`mydata` is a perfect location for this.  Instead of passing the `mydata.rating` property directly to the directive (and thus passing a value), pass the whole `mydata` object, and reference the `mydata.rating` property within the directive.  Since you're passing an object to the directive, it will be a reference, not a value, i.e. all of the directives which are passed the same `mydata` object will be looking at the same object, not copies of a particular property.  You could achieve the same goal by making the `rating` property an object as well instead of a value.

---

EDIT: in response to comments, you could change it to be more direct.

```
myDirectives.directive('myRating', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div><ul>' +
      '<li ng-click="setRating(1)">' +
      '  <img ng-src="img/{{ myData.rating >= 1 ? Unrated : Rated}}">' +
      '</li>' +
      '<li ng-click="setRating(2)">' +
      '  <img ng-src="img/{{ myData.rating >= 2 ? Unrated : Rated}}">' +
      '</li>' +
      '<li ng-click="setRating(3)">' +
      '  <img ng-src="img/{{ myData.rating >= 3 ? Unrated : Rated}}">' +
      '</li>' +
      '<li ng-click="setRating(4)">' +
      '  <img ng-src="img/{{ myData.rating >= 4 ? Unrated : Rated}}">' +
      '</li>' +
      '<li ng-click="setRating(5)">' +
      '  <img ng-src="img/{{ myData.rating >= 5 ? Unrated : Rated}}">' +
      '</li>' +
      '</ul></div>',

  scope: {
    myData: '=',  
    readonly: '@',
    onRatingSelected: '&'     
  },
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.setRating = function(val) {
      scope.myData.rating = val;          
      scope.onRatingSelected(scope.myData);
    } 
  }      
}
```

I don't expect this example to work with just copy/paste to your problem; it's just meant as an idea to get your rolling.

Comment: hey..thanks..I was able to add mydata.rating value to json, but how to loop throuh it in the directive? also scope.$watch(rating) doesnt works

Comment: I'm guessing this rating is a list of stars or some such.  If the max number of stars is always the same, don't use a loop, just create a list item for each one that is possible.  Then you don't need the repeat in the directive and just add a class to show the star as highlighted.  Check my edit for an example.